# golang and circle CI setup

Tags: cicd, circleci, go

Go and devops are both new things for me. I'd like to setup a CI that tests and builds my module, then stores artifacts for download. In addition it'd be good to cache dependencies for next builds.

I don't get how to do it using subdirectory for the go product. I want my git repository to look like that:

```
+ repository_root/
  + go/
    - go.mod
    - go.sum
    + hello/
      - main.go
  + cpp/
  + python/
  + .circleci/
```

go.mod

```
module github.com/{USER}/{REPOSITORY_ROOT}/go

go 1.14
```

Of course {USER} is replace with my github user name and {REPOSITORY_ROOT} is the repo name.

For now I have a following config.yml that doesn't work.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/project/go
    docker:
      - image: circleci/golang:1.9

    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/project/

      - run: mkdir bin
      - run: go get -v -t -d ./...
      - run: go test -v ./...
      - run: go build -o bin/hello.exe github.com/{USER}/{REPOSITORY_ROOT}/go/hello

      - store_artifacts:
          path: bin/
          destination: hello-app
```

Error on build command:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
go build -o ./bin/hello.exe github.com/{USER}/{REPO_ROOT}/go/hello
can't load package: package github.com/{USER}/{REPO_ROOT}/go/hello: cannot find package "github.com/{USER}/{REPO_ROOT}/go/hello" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/{USER}/{REPO_ROOT}/go/hello (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/{USER}/{REPO_ROOT}/go/hello (from $GOPATH)

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

I know that the module is outside of `GOPATH` but I have the same setup on my local machine and the same build command works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

My approach nowadays, always package your build process into Dockerfile. I.e. here is Dockerfile for one of my open-sourced Go projects:

https://github.com/relizaio/relizaGoClient/blob/master/Dockerfile

*Note*: if you're using go modules (which seems to be the case), replace `RUN go get -d -v ./...` with `RUN go mod download` in the build-stage. BTW, missing `go mod` instruction might be the reason for your build failure in the current setup.

Then in your CI, simply do `docker build` instruction, and then copy your artifact from the container if you need it outside.

*Key benefit*: you can verify build process against same Dockerfile locally and you can port it to any CI tool whatsoever.